# Screen resolution problem

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-float

I have this problem after coding my index page. I have divided the page into 2 columns:

```
header

nav

content floating left, content floating right

footer
```

On my screen resolution I have it properly aligned:

```
Content left | Content right
```

But on a small screen, it looks like this:

```
Content left
        Content right
```

This is the code:

```
    <div id="contentleft">
    text & content left
    </div>
    <div id="contentright">
    text & content right
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 #contentleft {
    float:left;
    margin-left:12%;}

#contentright {
    float:right;
    margin-right:12%;}
```

Help would be great appriciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

floats will wrap when there does not exist enough space for them. your css has the width set to auto expand to the content.

```
 #contentleft {
    float:left;
    margin-left:12%;
    width:38%; // note margins grow the width of divides
}

#contentright {
    float:right;
    margin-right:12%;
    width:37%; // note on odd width screen some browsers IE rounds up so 100%/2 + 100%/2 = 101% according to microsoft.
}
```

Comment: Thanks men! this got the effect I wanted only now contentleft is placed in a frame with a horizontal scrollbar... This happens on the small resolution screen.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: don't forget the document default css margin !!! if you don't wrap in a divide the default margin is 8 pixels for the screen breaking 100% width divides ... * {padding:0px; margin:0px} ... I seem to always miss this one on the first coding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is already in mt css document :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to prevent the overlap is to place both `div`s in a `#wrapper div` and give the `#wrapper` a set `width`.

```
#wrapper{
    width:400px;

}
#contentleft {
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    margin-left:12%;
    background:green;
}

#contentright {
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    margin-left:12%;
    background:red;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/b2eyx/1/

Fyi... I also floated them both left and changed the `margin`s and added some color to make it easier to see.

*And welcome to SO!*

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'll check if it works and let you know ;)

Answer (score 0):

add `width` to your Divs and put it in % like 50%-50%.

Comment: 50% + 12% + 50% + 12% > 100%, don't forget those margins.